# Nil result for class that has specified id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two classes, one for students and one for microposts. I'm trying to get the following result:

```
first_students = Student.first
# => #<User id: 1, name: "Michael Hartl", email: "michael@example.org",
# created_at: "2013-03-06 02:01:31", updated_at: "2013-03-06 02:01:31">
first_student.microposts
# => [#<Micropost id: 1, content: "First micropost!", user_id: 1, created_at:
# "2013-03-06 02:37:37", updated_at: "2013-03-06 02:37:37">, #<Micropost id: 2,
# content: "Second micropost", user_id: 1, created_at: "2013-03-06 02:38:54",
# updated_at: "2013-03-06 02:38:54">]
```

in the rails console. I am getting the first part, but when I say `first_student.microposts`, I get this:

```
SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."student_id" = ?  [[nil, 1]]
```

followed by an error message. I'm confused because I have a micropost with an id of `1` to match the student with an id of `1`. Any thoughts?

I'm following the coding instructions at [this link](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#top). I'm trying to create the app described in chapter 2. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you're defining a variable called `first_students`, then using `first_student` when calling the microposts method. I'd stick with the singular here.

Comment: you may have a problem in model definition? post you models and maybe the schema for student and microposts

Comment: I actually made a typo in this question. In the terminal I used first_student. Same error message. Any new thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer. As it turns out, I had used user and student interchangeably when I created the scaffold because I wanted my application to use student but the tutorial was using user. That made it difficult to remember to change all the time, and as a result I was using user where I should have used student. Thanks for the great answers though! If I have a similar problem I'll know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Make the models associations proper and then try it.

but in first line you have find first student and the model which dispatch record is User is it all right or you have done something wrong.